# Use of reflection and DRYing out some code

Tags: go, reflection, dry

I have a function that needs to receive a type, determine the subtype, then create a copy of the subtype.  I keep staring at this function and I feel this can be simplified, but I just can't figure out how to get it functioning.  Here's the code:

```
func AddProp(prop prop, x, y int) []prop {

  v := reflect.ValueOf(prop)
  fmt.Printf("Prop type is %v", v.Type())

  switch v.Type() {
  case reflect.TypeOf(&Fence{}):
      f := Fence{}
      f.New(x, y)
      props = append(props, &f)
  case reflect.TypeOf(&Rock{}):
      f := Rock{}
      f.New(x, y)
      props = append(props, &f)
  }
  return props
}
```

It's actually quite a bit longer than this with many more cases.  Thank you for taking a look!

Edit:
Perfectly reasonable question - what is a prop?

```
type prop interface {
    New(int, int)
}
```

Second Edit:
My structs looks like this:

```
type Prop struct {
    fullImage image.Image
    x, y int
}
type Fence struct {
    Prop
    horizontal bool
}
```

I have New(x,y int) defined for both

```
func (p *Prop) New(x, y int)
func (p *Fence) New(x, y int)
```

I need to get the Fence struct and call the New based on the Fence and not the Prop

Comment: what is prop ??

Comment: There are no subtypes in Go.

Comment: A function named `New` that returns nothing... doesn't feel much like Go. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this provided all types have the `New` method:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {

    props := AddProp(&Rock{}, 1, 1)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", props)

    props = AddProp(&Fence{}, 1, 1)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", props)

}

type Rock struct{}

func (r *Rock) New(x, y int) {}

type Fence struct{}

func (r *Fence) New(x, y int) {}

type prop interface {
    New(x, y int)
}

func AddProp(p prop, x, y int) (props []prop) {
    newValue := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(p).Elem()).Interface()
    z := newValue.(prop)
    z.New(x, y)
    props = append(props, z)
    return props
}
```

Comment: it needs, i think, an additional check to test if given prop is of kind ptr. https://play.golang.org/p/XQwt2-AQtth

Comment: but i am still unsure if it should always return ptr to the underlying type or the same as the input.

Comment: @mh-cbon, messed up the pointers, the updated should work provided prop is a pointer to a struct

Comment: neyh sorry, the compiler still complains ;) I will update if you dont mind.

Comment: Sure, go ahead. But in your playground code, the second instance of the call is using a struct, not a &struct

Comment: yes, i am not totally clear if OP send struct value of ptr values. i have some doubt he knows himself : /

Comment: The OP is checking for struct pointers in the type switch

Comment: miight be better with https://play.golang.org/p/ucEb0ffHNn9

Comment: It has to pass pointers, because otherwise `New(x,y)` won't work assuming it initializes the underlying struct.

Comment: This is soo, close, but the append needs to convert back to a prop value.  This is where I keep having trouble.  Thank you!

Comment: @JeremyWebb, prop appears to be an interface, and the code does that already

Comment: I got ride of indirect to make things all simpler, assuming the input value must be a ptr. https://play.golang.org/p/ZxeBEeqObKj